# FileSink in Apache Flink not generating logs in output folder

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am using Apache Flink to read data from kafka topic and to store it in files on server. I am using FileSink to store files, it creates the directory structure date and time wise but no logs files are getting created.

When i run the program it creates directory structure as below but log files are not getting stored here.

```
/flink/testlogs/2021-12-08--07 
/flink/testlogs/2021-12-08--06
```

I want the log files should be written every 15 mins to a new log file.
Below is the code.

```
DataStream <String> kafkaTopicData = env.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer<String>("MyTopic",new SimpleStringSchema(),p)); 

OutputFileConfig config = OutputFileConfig
                 .builder()
                 .withPartPrefix("prefix")
                 .withPartSuffix(".ext")
                 .build();

DataStream <Tuple6 < String,String,String ,String, String ,Integer >> newStream=kafkaTopicData.map(new LogParser());

final FileSink<Tuple6<String, String, String, String, String, Integer>> sink = FileSink.forRowFormat(new Path("/flink/testlogs"),
                  new SimpleStringEncoder < Tuple6 < String,String,String ,String, String ,Integer >> ("UTF-8"))
                .withRollingPolicy(DefaultRollingPolicy.builder()
                        .withRolloverInterval(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(15))
                        .withInactivityInterval(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(5))
                        .withMaxPartSize(1024 * 1024 * 1024)
                        .build())
                .withOutputFileConfig(config)
                .build();
    
        newStream.sinkTo(sink);

env.execute("DataReader");  

LogParser returns Tuple6.
```

Comment: Is checkpointing enabled? The FileSink only finalizes the files it writes when checkpoints complete.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Checkpointing is not enabled. Can you advise how to enable it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When used in streaming mode, Flink's `FileSink` requires that checkpointing be enabled. To do this, you need to specify where you want checkpoints to be stored, and at what interval you want them to occur.

To configure this in `flink-conf.yaml`, you would do something like this:

```yaml
state.checkpoints.dir: s3://checkpoint-bucket
execution.checkpointing.interval: 10s
```

Or in your application code you can do this:

```java
env.getCheckpointConfig().setCheckpointStorage("s3://checkpoint-bucket");
env.enableCheckpointing(10000L);
```

Another important detail from the [docs](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/connectors/datastream/file_sink/#important-considerations):

> Given that Flink sinks and UDFs in general do not differentiate between normal job termination (e.g. finite input stream) and termination due to failure, upon normal termination of a job, the last in-progress files will not be transitioned to the “finished” state.

Comment: Thanks it fixed the issue now files are getting created. However i set the Rolling interval to 15 mins but files get created every minute.  withRollingPolicy(DefaultRollingPolicy.builder()
            .withRolloverInterval(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(15))